# ¿Cuál es el fallo al aplicar una clase definida en css sobre una etiqueta?

Tags: html, css

Sobre un párrafo en html aplico una clase:

```
<body>
     <p class="prueba">cualquier texto</p>
</body>
```

En el código css tengo lo siguiente:

```
body {
    color:#0000FF;  
    font-size: 10px;
}

.prueba {
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Todo funciona correctamente pero si modifico el html del siguiente modo (añadiendo una etiqueta `<hr>` dentro del párrafo):

```
<body>
     <p class="prueba">cualquier texto<hr>otro texto de prueba</p>
</body>
```

Observo que solo se aplica la clase hasta la etiqueta `<hr>` en lugar de hacerlo sobre todo el párrafo. ¿Al estar la clase definida sobre la etiqueta `<p>`, no debiera aplicarse a todo su contenido?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

El significado de la etiqueta `<hr>` ha cambiado en HTML5. Se interpreta como un cambio de tema entre párrafos, una separación entre los párrafos previos y los posteriores, un corte en la historia...

Por eso no tiene demasiado sentido que se encuentre dentro de un párrafo y el comportamiento de los navegadores en este caso puede ser imprevisto.

En versiones anteriores de HTML sí que representaba una línea horizontal pero actualmente se le da un significado más semántico: como separador de textos. Aunque los navegadores, principalmente por motivos de compatibilidad, la siguen representando por defecto como una línea horizontal.

Referencia: [<hr> - HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/hr)